# Невозможно разрешить метод

Tags: java, android

Добрый день. Во Fragmente обрабатываю json и при помощи кастомного адаптера отправляю в лист вью.

```
    public class DialogF extends Fragment {
ListView dialogList;
    ArrayList<DialogSaveData> UpList = new ArrayList<>();
    public DialogF() {
        //Требуемый пустой публичный конструктор
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_dialog, container, false);
dialogList = (ListView)view.findViewById(R.id.dialogList);

        return view;
    }

    public void setResult(String result){


        JSONObject jsonObject = null;

        try {
            jsonObject = new JSONObject(result);

            JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("dialog");

            for(int i = 0; i<jsonArray.length(); i++){
                JSONObject productObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                UpList.add(new DialogSaveData(
                        productObject.getString("avatar"),
                        productObject.getString("name"),
                        productObject.getString("text"),
                        productObject.getString("state")

                ));

            }

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }



      CastomDialog adapter = new CastomDialog(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.castom_dialog_list, UpList);
        // присваиваем адаптер списку
      dialogList.setAdapter(adapter);




    }




}
```

на строчке  `CastomDialog adapter = new CastomDialog(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.castom_dialog_list, UpList);` красным подсвечивается `getApplicationContext()` , пишет что невозможно разрешить данный метод. Подскажите пожалуйста как можно решить эту проблему?

Comment: класс `Fragment` не имеет метода `getApplicationContext()`, используйте метод `getActivity()` для получения контекста

Answer (score 0):

Можно- getActivity().getApplicationContext()
Создайте отдельно контекст и передайте: private Context context; и в CastomDialog adapter = new CastomDialog(context, R.layout.castom_dialog_list, UpList);

Или еще можно передавать во фрагмент context главной активити как аргумент.

Comment: Пожалуйста,  дайте более развёрнутый ответ.

Comment: Создайте отдельно контекст и передайте:  private Context context; и в CastomDialog adapter = new CastomDialog(context, R.layout.castom_dialog_list, UpList);

Comment: Или еще можно передавать во фрагмент context главной активити как аргумент.

Comment: Перенесите комментарии в ответ [править](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/712466/edit), их обычно никто не читает.